# Conflict between local DNS zone and country domain name

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

I have recently setup a new Windows 2003 server for a regional office in Germany. The server has been setup as a child domain on our corporate setup and, being in Germany, the domain was called de, so the full name for the child is de.ourcompanyname.lan

This seems to have upset DNS resolution for any public .de domains (eg: www.microsoft.de).

The (DNS) server has forwarders set to an external DNS service (Google at the moment), so I presumed that this would ensure any names not resolved internally would be handled, but apparently not so.

The setup process has created a forward lookup zone called de - not sure if this is part of the problem,

Was the internal naming convention not a good idea, or should it not have been an issue!? Any guidance or hints on diagnosing this would be appreciated.

Edit:

I might have fixed this by replacing the 'de' forward lookup zone with one called 'de.ourcompany.lan' - would that be a correct/expected fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think yes. With that forward zone you practically took over .de domain.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your redesign of the forwarders are the solution. You can't just forward the .de TLD and expect everything to work :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Laurentiu just got in there by a minute though